# link to a given page of an epub file from org mode

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to make a link from org mode to a given page or section of an epub file (epub warp) ?

I know that with "pdfview:./filename.pdf::6" we can have access to the page 6 of the pdf file.
So I tried "file:filename.epub": it opens the epub file in another buffer. But it opens it at the index section.
How to specify the page/section to open?
I tried something like "file:filename.epub::num_in_the_epub_file.xhtml#ch3" or several variations around that but it does not work.

I also tried 
M-x org-store-link / M-x org-insert-link
but it seems that it does not work with epub file...

Any ideas? Thanks by advance

Comment: This depends on the EPUB package you use. Mine (nov.el) doesn't support the notion of pages at all...

Comment: I have (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.epub\\'" . nov-mode)) in my init.el... so it should be nov.el. My need is not necessary to jump to a given page. If it's possible to jump to a given section that would be perfect also. Thanks.

Comment: well... my question seems not to be a hot topic... :-) I will post a new comment if I find a solution.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this? I'm wondering if its possible to link to a specific string in an epub file.

Answer (score 1):

Using `nov.el`, <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> (`org-store-link`) at point in epub file + <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-l</kbd> (`org-insert-link`) at point where link is needed worked for me.

The resultant link would look something like this:

```org
[[nov:~/Calibre Library/Sonke Ahrens/How to Take Smart Notes_ One Simple Technique to Boost Writing, Learning and Thinking - for Stud (29)/How to Take Smart Notes_ One Simple Techni - Sonke Ahrens.epub::7:16535][link]]
```